# Ruby regexp optional repeating groups?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to extract multiple substrings from a string in Ruby using a regular expression.

This is my string: `text.1.2.3.4.5`.

What I'd like is to have a match with multiple groups like the following:

```
text
.1
.2
.3
.4
.5
```

`text` can be any word character. The rest must be groups of `\.\d*` but there can be none. So a string like this: `text` should get matched with only one captured result which is `text`.

This is what I tried but it's not working as expected. I'm only getting the `text` and the last group `.5`:

```
^(\w*)(?:(\.\d+)|$)*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"text.1.2.3.4.5".scan(/\A\w+|\.\d*/)
# => ["text", ".1", ".2", ".3", ".4", ".5"]
```

Comment: Nice! `scan` is something I didn't know about. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a regex hero, but here is my shot:

```
(\w*)(\.\d+)?
```

It seems rather simple but also seem to do the trick (except for the extra empty match at the end)
Check out http://rubular.com/r/xAqgUqERa7 to play with it

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```
> "text.1.2.3.4.5".scan(/([a-zA-Z]+|\.\d+)/)
=> [["text"], [".1"], [".2"], [".3"], [".4"], [".5"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work `(\w*)(\.\d+)`

Comment: this only matches `1:"text" 2:".1"`